# vue.config.js - yaml-loader and i18n not working together

Tags: yaml, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I'm working on vuejs3 project, where I need to load config file written in yaml. This is done by

```
    config.module
      .rule('yaml')
        .test(/\.ya?ml?$/)
        .use('yaml-loader')
          .loader('yaml-loader')
          .end();
  }
```

in vue.config.js. Then I want to add translations by using i18n package and want to have separated translations in each .vue file, like

```
<i18n lang="yaml">
en:
  hello: "hello world!"
ja:
  hello: "こんにちは、世界！"
</i18n>
```

in yaml format. As suggested I added this block of code to vue.config.js

```
    config.module
      .rule('i18n')
        .type('javascript/auto')
        .resourceQuery(/blockType=i18n/)
        .use('i18n')
          .loader('@intlify/vue-i18n-loader')
          .end();
```

but it causes error `YAMLParseError: Implicit keys need to be on a single line at line 1, column 1:`.

When I remove the translation section `<i18n lang="yaml">...</i18n>`, there is no error. When I remove the `config.module.rule('yaml') ...` and loading of .yaml config file, translations works fine.
Unfortunately it is not working together.

Thanks for any ideas in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same as you did, and neither not woking.

Though this works for me, but I don't really know why, hope this works for you, too.

```
    // let webpack to recognize i18n tag
    config.module
      .rule('i18n')
      .resourceQuery(/blockType=i18n/)
      .type('javascript/auto')
      .use('i18n')
      .loader('@intlify/vue-i18n-loader')
    // use @intlify/vue-i18n-loader instead of yaml loader
    config.module
      .rule('yaml')
      .test(/\.ya?ml$/)
      .type('javascript/auto')
      .use('yaml')
      .loader('@intlify/vue-i18n-loader')
```

`@infinity/vue-i18n-loader` has `js-yaml` itself, so you can use it just fine. https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-loader/blob/v1.x/package.json

If there's further idea, please let me know.